# How to declare an unmodifiable serializable List in Java

Tags: java, collections, serializable

Given a class with a List field:

```
public class A implements Serializable {
    private final List<String> names;

    public A(List<String> names) {
        this.names = List.copyOf(names);
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

The compiler issues a warning that the field is not serializable.

The unmodifiable list returned by `List.copyOf` is serializable, so in reality it isn't a problem. But I want to get rid of the warning - what's the cleanest way to implement this?

Note: When the field doesn't need to be unmodifiable I could make it an `ArrayList` (instead of `List`) and copy the names in the constructor with `new ArrayList(names)` (instead of `List.copyOf(names)`). But then (obviously) the list is modifiable.

So I guess my question is: How do I declare an unmodifiable serializable List?

Comment: Does `Collections.unmodifiableList(names)` work for you?

Comment: No, the same question remains. Both List.copyOf and Collections.unmodifialbeList return a List (the interface) which does not extend Serializable. So this doesn't help - even if the actually returned implementation does implement Serializable.

Comment: The actual list types returned by `List.of` and `List.copyOf` **are** serializable, as are the actual list types returned by `Collections.unmodifiableList`. You can only suppress the warning by using `@SuppressWarnings("serial")`, even the Java code itself does this (e.g. in `Collections.UnmodifiableCollection`)

Comment: (To be clear, for `Collections.unmodifiableList`, this requires that the wrapped list is serializable)

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel. Yes, I'm aware of that and I suspected, that suppressing the warning might be the way to go. Just wanted to check if anyone had another idea ... Looks to me like a flaw in the Java Collection Framework.

Comment: @Nausika They have decided not to get mired down in an explosion of interfaces to address these kinds of things (especially as using `Serializable` is basically discouraged). It is not even the worst offense in its design (e.g. consider the fact that immutable lists are indistinguishable from mutable lists until you call a mutating method). And if you really want to be sure, you can always customize serialization (e.g. with `writeObject`/`readObject` and/or `readResolve`/`writeReplace`

Comment: I personally hate this new compiler warning.  It actively discourages the use of interfaces like List as types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java [guarantees](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) that the actual list implementations returned by `List.of` and `List.copyOf` are serializable (if their element type is serializable, obviously), so you don't need to do anything to make them serializable. The  problem is that you declare the list variable as a `List`, and that is not guaranteed to be serializable (`List` itself does not extend `Serializable`), so a warning is emitted.

There is no way to handle this other than to add a `@SuppressWarnings("serial")` on the field (or class) because your implementation *knows* it always uses a serializable implementation.

The suggestion by [wypieprz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2754530/wypieprz) in the comments to use `Collections.unmodifiableList` is not a good alternative because, although the actual type returned by this method also implements `Serializable`, the actual serializability depends on whether or not the list passed in is serializable. You would then need to make a defensive copy anyway (checking if the passed in list implements `Serializable` is not sufficient, because you could be receiving the return value of `Collections.unmodifiableList` yourself). And if you need to make a copy, using `List.copyOf` is a better choice.